# Vue3 - How to override styles after importing node_modules css file?

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a standard Vue3 app using the library https://github.com/ismail9k/vue3-carousel.

In my `App.vue` file, I have the following, which is required to use the library:

```
<style>
@import "~vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.css";
</style>
```

Since I don't want to use the library's default colors, I'm trying to override some styles.

The library defines some colors on `:root`, such as:

```
--vc-clr-primary: #333333;
--vc-pgn-background-color: var(--vc-clr-primary);
```

Then, the style that I want to ultimately override is:

```
.carousel__pagination-button {
  ...
  background-color: var(--vc-pgn-background-color);
}
```

So, I assume that I want to override either of the variables, or the class itself. In my `Component.vue` file, I have the following:

```
<style scoped>
.carousel__pagination-button {
  background-color: #999999 !important;
}
</style>
```

But that doesn't do anything.

I don't care where I override these colors, because I'll use the same colors throughout the website, but I can't figure out how to get them to override no matter where or how I attempt to override them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

## App.vue

```
...

<style>
#app {
  --vc-pgn-background-color: #mycolor;
}

@import "~vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.css";
</style>
```

Comment: I think you could even just put :root { } in your styles, to override the global styles globally. Perhaps in a dedicated css file though, not sure how that is looked upon in Vuejs nowadays. In any way, you can mark your own answer as accepted here :)

Comment: I think I tried that, and I don't think it worked, but don't quote me... my goldfish memory doesn't go back that far.